# Product of every element of two linear arrays

Tags: python, list

How can I multiply every element of two linear arrays with each other, i.e. if I got these two arrays:

```
x=[1, 4, 0 ,3]
y=[2, 1, 9 ,4]
```

I would like to get the following one as the output :

```
z=[2, 4, 0, 12]
```

Comment: If you want to work with numpy as it seems, you need to define them as numpy arrays, so: `np.array([1, 4, 0 ,3])`. Then you just need to multiply them ( `*`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is one way; using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both lists simultaneously:

```
z = [a * b for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

a different way is to use [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 4, 0 ,3])
y = np.array([2, 1, 9 ,4])

z = x * y
print(z)  # [ 2  4  0 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inbuilt function `zip` and list comprehension :

```
z = [i*j for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.zip()` to accomplish just that

Using list comprehension:

```
[x*y for x,y in zip(list_x,list_y)]
```

Without list comprehension:

```
for x,y in zip(list_x,list_y):
    print(x*y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a different option:

```
>>> x=[1, 4, 0 ,3]
>>> y=[2, 1, 9 ,4]
>>> import operator
>>> list(map(operator.mul, x, y))
[2, 4, 0, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication of two array is only possible when size of both arrays are equal in length.

Try this code !

**Code :**

```
x=[1, 4, 0 ,3]
y=[2, 1, 9 ,4]
z= []
if (len(x)==len(y)):
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        z.append(x[i]*y[i])
    print(z)
else:
    print("Array are not equal in size.... Multiplication is not possible")
```

**Output :**

```
[2, 4, 0, 12]
```